# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, динамические-массивы

Не могу закрыть всплывающее окно, даже путем xpath, но не понимаю почему

```
import requests, bs4
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1200,900)
website = "https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/XRP_USDT?layout=basic&type=spot"
driver.get(website)
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]').click()
driver.close()
```

Пробовал нажимать и на svg тоже не получалось, не понимаю в чем причина ошибки

Comment: я открыл, вашим xpath'ом  не получил. вот таки каким-то `(/html/body/div/div/div)[2]`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, у меня заработало, но с чем это связанно ?! Я добавил 1 скобочку в начале ...

Comment: это просто совсем разные xpath'ы.  Проверить xpath можно в том же хроме в консоле `$x('ваш_xpath')`

Comment: Спасибо, про проверку xpath я такого не знал. А что на счет вашего xpath, это же не xpath крестика, как окно закрылось?

Comment: Это xpath к div, содержащему крестик